# How can I save my response into a list in BASH?

Tags: arrays, bash, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

My first bash script.

```sh
myvar=$(aws ec2 describe-regions|jq '.Regions[] | {RegionName: .RegionName }')
echo "${myvar}"| jq -c '.| .RegionName'
```

Using the 2 commands above. I successfully got the the following result in terminal

```
"af-south-1"
"eu-north-1"
"ap-south-1"
"eu-west-3"
"eu-west-2"
"eu-west-1"
"ap-northeast-3"
"ap-northeast-2"
"me-south-1"
"ap-northeast-1"
"sa-east-1"
"ca-central-1"
"ap-east-1"
"ap-southeast-1"
"ap-southeast-2"
"eu-central-1"
"us-east-1"
"us-east-2"
"us-west-1"
"us-west-2"
```

How to save the answer into an array, and iterate it?

I thought about

```sh
awsRegionList =$(${myvar}| jq -c '.| .RegionName')
echo awsRegionList
```

But it finishes with an error.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can simplify the `jq` query to process the EC2 output in one go.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Map the output of jq parsed EC2 response into the $regionList array
mapfile -d '' regionList < <(
  # Gets EC2 response in JSON piped
  aws ec2 describe-regions |

  # Processes JSON into a null-delimited stream
  jq --join-output '.Regions[] | .RegionName + "\u0000"'
)

# Iterates the list
for regionName in "${regionList[@]}"; do

  # Do stuffs with $regionName
  printf 'Doing stuff with: %s\n' "$regionName"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a single `jq` command to save the output into an array. Afterwards you can iterate over it with a `for` loop:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

awsRegionList=($(aws ec2 describe-regions | jq -r -c '.Regions[] | .RegionName'))

for region in ${awsRegionList[@]}; do
    echo $region
done;
```

Note, using `-r` will remove the quotes as well, so the output will be something like:

```
eu-north-1
ap-south-1
eu-west-3
eu-west-2
eu-west-1
ap-northeast-3
ap-northeast-2
ap-northeast-1
sa-east-1
ca-central-1
ap-southeast-1
ap-southeast-2
eu-central-1
us-east-1
us-east-2
us-west-1
us-west-2
```

Comment: `awsRegionList=$(aws ec2 describe-regions | jq -r -c '.Regions[] | .RegionName')` is capturing the output as a string, not an array. It cannot be iterated. `for region in ${awsRegionList[@]};` is just splitting words by `IFS` delimiter (including spaces) and illegally use an array syntax over a string variable.

Comment: thanks i actually used it 
for region in ${awsRegionList[@]}; do
   # echo "working on $region"
    aws ec2 --region=$region describe-volumes --filters Name=status,Values=available|jq '.Volumes[] | { State: .State, VolumeId: .VolumeId, Tags: .Tags }'
done;

But the response:" Invalid endpoint: https://ec2."ap-northeast-2".amazonaws.com"

While I am using the next one I am succeed :
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=status,Values=available|jq '.Volumes[] | { State: .State, VolumeId: .VolumeId, Tags: .Tags }' )
echo "$awsvalue

Do you know why ?

Comment: Your URL `ec2."ap-northeast-2".amazonaws.com` contains quotes `("")`. You would want to get rid of them. Please post it as another question, otherwise other people wont be able to see this comment and help you with it.